# How do I make a string with a fixed string (area code) and ad dynamic string (@phone)

Tags: json

I am extremely new at JSON environment, I am building a robot for Whatsapp, using an existing endpoint, we obtain the customer's phone without the area code and they can get their account balance.  Since they don't type the area code, I need to pass that as a fixed variable called @araecode with a value of (507) then I pass that to a webhook where I have {"number": "@phone"} ... how could I concatenate the 507 to the @phone and make it one string to send with POST to get the account balance. I know very little about JSON, but I am an old school programmer.  THanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: example: customer inputs 66138992 and I need to pass 50766138992 to the webhook.

Comment: I was asking to see what you have so far. It’s common to post the code you have so people can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: many thanks so I am using a bot which is from Landbot , one of their many module is called webhook , you can choose POST , GET etc, input the URL and you can set the variables , then headers if needed, and then the body.  Our endpoint uses POST the URL the only variable that has "number" is all setup in the body part, and this is the code there is in there:

Comment: {"number": "@phone"}

Comment: where phone is input by the customer on whatsapp

Comment: the problem I have is I need to append 507 in front of that @phone variable.and I have no clue I am sorry I don't have more code to share.  That is all my team provided so i am trying to figure this out on my own

Comment: "Landbot Webhook blocks do not accept XML, only JSON"